# Day/night theme according to the time

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, application-settings

I'm developing an android app where i want to have a night theme also. I don't know how to proceed here. I want an option to be set in settings that automatically set the day/night theme. And theme should be set according to the time same as in google maps.

How can i do this?

Comment: Do you have any code from where you are stuck or getting an error?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the timings at which the night theme would be changed. Checkout the this [AppCompat v23.2 — DayNight](https://medium.com/@chrisbanes/appcompat-v23-2-daynight-d10f90c83e94#.mv5opva1q)

Comment: This answer relies almost completely on external links. Should they ever become invalid, the answer would be useless. So please [edit] it and add at least a summary of what can be found there. Thank you!